# What does adapter means in socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io these days, but I don't really understand what does adapter means in socket.io. Can anybody explain it to me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

`Socket.IO` applications can be scaled out by using an adapter to distribute messages and events between multiple application instances.
By running socket.io with the `socket.io-redis adapter` you can run multiple socket.io instances in different processes or servers that can all broadcast and emit events to and from each other.

**Passing events between nodes**

Now that you have multiple Socket.IO nodes accepting connections, if you want to broadcast events to everyone (or even everyone in a certain room) you’ll need some way of `passing messages between processes or computers.`
The interface in charge of routing messages is what we **`call the Adapter.`** You can implement your own on top of the socket.io-adapter (by inheriting from it) or you can use the one we provide on top of Redis: socket.io-redis:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(3000);
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks, mate.